# Where in ViewController should UIGestureRecognizer be set up?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

If `ViewController`'s view is set to `MyView`

[image]

[image]

And ViewController maintains a pointer to it's view (set up via storyboards)

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MyView *v;
```

Where in `ViewController`, should the following take place?

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] 
             initWithTarget:v action:@selector(pan:)];
[v addGestureRecognizer: panGesture];
```

Comment: in `viewDidLoad`. There v will already created.

Comment: Why don't you drag the gesture recognizer in the storyboard?

Comment: @dasdom I find code to be clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is a good place for this kind of initialization, since the view hierarchy will have been loaded into memory at that point, whether it was loaded from a storyboard or nib, or created programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears you are using a XIB file for your view, `viewDidLoad` is proper.