# On UIGestureRecognizers, clarification needed

Tags: ios

Other then setting UIGestureRecognizers in a Controller:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
               initWithTarget:v action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
swipeGesture.direction= UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[v addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
```

And making a method in a view available

```
-(void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Swipe detected");
}
```

Is there anything else needed? If not, what am i missing please? When gesture is simulated, NSlog is not printing

Comment: By the way. How do you simulate the swipe? Are you doing it with UIAutomation? Then you have to move also a bit in x direction.

Comment: I believe swipe is nothing but a fast pan over a small distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

I see from [your recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9895747/927947) that you are also using a pan gesture recognizer. Gesture recognizers don't really know how to play well with each-other without instruction. You have two main options

1) One or the other:

```
[panGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeGesture];
```

The pan only fires if the touch is not a swipe. or-

2) Both at the same time:

Conform the the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol.

Set the delegates:

```
panGesture.delegate = self;
swipeGesture.delegate = self;
```

And implement the method:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
```

**Original**

Right now you are setting your view `v` as the target of the recognizer, so essentially when the swipe is detected the recognizer calls:

```
[v handleSwipe:self];
```

It seems more likely that both of your methods are in a view controller. If that's the case then the init method should look like this:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
           initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
```

Since `v` is the intended target and with that in mind your code is fine; I would think the next most likely cause is that your first chunk of code runs before the view `v` loads. i.e. the code is not in `viewDidLoad` after `v` already exists. If you're unsure a simple log will confirm it's existence:

```
NSLog(@"v is %@",v);
```

If that proves to be a dead-end we will definitely require more info on this view `v`. What is it's superclass? Are there other recognizers on it? How is it added to the `view`?

Comment: @dasdom Thanks. But your answer is probably right. It would explain why he's just not getting a log statement as opposed to the crash he would get if I was right.

Comment: In reality, ViewController only does the setup of the GestureRecognizers, View provides the code that handles it. Changing the initialization to what you suggested, did not seem to solve the problem, unfortunately. In my example, target is `v`. This is intended.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the view accepts user interaction. This can be done in storyboard or via [[myView setUserInteractionEnabled: YES]](http://file:///Users/dom/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS5_1.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled).